# Negate this statement: There exist $x, y ∈ \Bbb{R}$ such that $x < y$ and $x^2 > y^2$

Tags: proof-explanation, solution-verification

> Negate this statement:
>
> There exist $x, y ∈ \Bbb{R}$ such that $x < y$ **and** $x^2 > y^2$

From my understanding,

"there exists" becomes "for all"

"and" becomes "or" by De Morgan's laws

equality signs "reverse"

> So, our negated statement is:
>
> For all $x, y ∈ \Bbb{R}$, $x ≥ y$ **or** $x^2 ≤ y^2$

However, the textbook's answer says that the negated statement is:

[image]

I do not understand why the negated "implies" $x^2 ≥ y^2$  at the very end. Wouldn't it be $x^2 ≤ y^2$ (to "reverse" the equality sign)? Any clarification would be much appreciated!

This is from a grade 11 Maths Specialist textbook on proofs involving the use of negation.

Comment: I think one way of seeing the given statement is $\exists x,y$ such that $x\lt y \Leftrightarrow x^2\gt y^2$.

Comment: Why did they add "Intent" ?

Comment: @user710290: I can't agree with that.

Comment: As an aside, the statement is true if $x<0$ and $|x|>|y|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wording is a little clumsy, but you are right. The negation is

$$\forall x,y\in \mathbb R: x\ge y\lor x^2\le y^2.$$

Given that

$$a\implies b\equiv \lnot a\lor b$$ we can also write

$$\forall x,y\in \mathbb R: x<y\implies x^2\le y^2.$$

I also disagree with the book.

Answer (score 0):

The first two lines below are equivalent to each other because of what you said about quantifiers. The second and third are equivalent to each other by de Morgan's law:
\begin{align}
& \lnot \exists x,y\in\mathbb R\,\, \big( x<y\ \&\ x^2>y^2 \big) \\[8pt]
& \forall x,y\in\mathbb R\,\, \lnot\big(x<y\ \&\ x^2 > y^2\big) \\[8pt]
& \forall x,y\in\mathbb R\,\, \big( x\ge y \text{ or } x^2 \le y^2 \big)
\end{align}
Your words "such that" don't make sense. So it seems that you and the book both got it wrong. But what you wrote doesn't seem substantially different from what the book said.

Comment: What the OP wrote doesn't seem substantially different from what you said.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : The OP had those word "such that" in a place where they syntactically don't fit.

Comment: I know, and when you drop this, what remains is correct (i.e. the essential predicates). IMO it is too much to say that the OP got it wrong.

Comment: @MichaelHardy - yes my bad, I forgot to remove that (edited now) Thanks